# A question on closed operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

In my functional analysis book, there is a theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed linear spaces over a field $F$. Then, a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ is closed if and only if, for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $(x_n)\to x$ and $T(x_n)\to y$, we have $x\in X$ and $T(x)=y$.

Following the theorem, there is the following exercise:

$\textbf{Exercise:}$ Prove that the derivative operator from $P[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ is a closed operator. Here, $P[0,1]$ is the space of all polynomials with the domain considered as $[0,1]$, and $C[0,1]$ is the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$, both with the sup norm.

But according to me if $x_n\to x$ , then there is no guarantee that $x\in P[0,1]$ as this space is not complete. so by above theorem operator is not closed . Where is my mistake ? Please suggest . Thank you.

Comment: Well, maybe if you explained why you think $x_n \to x$ need not imply $x \in P[0,1]$, we would have a start... we can't exactly criticize an argument you don't show to us.

Comment: @PrincessEev because the space is not complete.

Comment: It is **given** that $x_n \to x$ in $P[0,1]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm in theorem this is not so .

Comment: @geetha290krm if it is given then there is no problem.

Comment: @PrincessEev Sequence of polynomials may not uniformly convergent to a polynomial. I am saying because of Weierstrass approximation Theorem.

Comment: @BrunoB but in the theorem there is no such assumption. Rather according to theorem we have to prove that $x$ is in X.

Comment: I am not able to understand the theorem .

Comment: This exercise and the statement of that theorem are somewhat confusing to be fair, since you wouldn't need to prove that $x \in X$ if the convergence is already in $X$. What is the book you're referring to?

Comment: @BrunoB is local book of my area. Not a standard international book.

Comment: @BrunoB https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedOperator.html here is also same definition.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Closed_operator

Comment: It's not really the same as your book. You'll note that the operator (named $A$ in those pages) has a domain $D(A)$ which is still included in a bigger complete space $X$, and that's where proving that $x \in D(A)$ becomes important, because you're looking at a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset D(A)$ converging to some $x \in X$. With your book's theorem, you seemingly lose that domain part...

Comment: @BrunoB I will think about it again  and will comment .

Comment: @BrunoB and in question part  of exercise ? In this question it is given that poly sequence already convergent to a polynomial sequence?

Comment: With your book's conventions and how it's framed, I'd say that yes, here you have a sequence of polynomials already converging to a polynomial.

Comment: @BrunoB ok thank you.